# VB.NET - System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory...' Occurs sporadically when using autoCompleteSource

Tags: vb.net

System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

I started getting this exception after trying to implement AutoComplete into one of my text boxes. It seems to occur somewhat sporadically? It often occurs when trying to use AutoComplete within a couple seconds of loading it's panel but has occured upwards of 5/6 seconds afterwards too. Additionally if it doesn't occur, the AutoComplete can be used endlessly without crashing.
I've had the same error occur on two different machines so I'm really unsure of what could be causing this and would be endlessly grateful if someone could point me in the right direction!

I've tried to strip out all the parts that definitely aren't causing it to save space.
This code runs first:

```
    Private Sub btnManagerEditItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnManagerEditItem.Click
        refreshEditItemsScreen(False) ' clears all on screen data and repopulates DataGrid
        txtManagerEditItemsSearchName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        txtManagerEditItemsSearchName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    End Sub
```

```
    Private Sub refreshEditItemsScreen(refreshDatabase As Boolean)
        dtgrdManagerEditItems.Rows.Clear() ' DataGridView displays items to user.
        If refreshDatabase Then
            updateItemDatabase() ' reads the database from file and updates _itemDatabase with it
        End If
        For Each entry In _itemDatabase ' Global variable holding the database
            dtgrdManagerEditItems.Rows.Add(entry.Name, entry.Price.ToString("c"), entry.UniqueID, getStaffDictionary(entry.StaffID))
        Next
    End Sub
```

```
    Private Sub updateItemDatabase()
        _itemDatabase = readItemDatabaseFromFile()
    End Sub
```

```
    Private Function readItemDatabaseFromFile() As List(Of Item)
        Dim pathtofile As String = IO.Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.Substring(0, My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.Length - 21), "Item Database.xml")
        Dim itemDatabaseFromFile As New List(Of Item)
        If System.IO.File.Exists(pathtofile) Then
            Dim objStreamReader As New StreamReader(pathtofile)
            Dim xsSerialize As New XmlSerializer(itemDatabaseFromFile.GetType)
            itemDatabaseFromFile = xsSerialize.Deserialize(objStreamReader)
            objStreamReader.Close()
        End If
        Return itemDatabaseFromFile
    End Function
```

Then this code runs when you start typing in the AutoCorrect box:

```
    Private Sub txtManagerEditItemsName_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtManagerEditItemsSearchName.TextChanged
        txtManagerEditItemsSearchName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = _autoCompleteSource
    End Sub
```

_autoCompleteSource gets it's value when this code is ran on form load (updateItemDatabase() is also ran on form load):

```
    Private Sub updateAutoCompleteSource()
        ' reads the id dictionary from file and adds it to the auto complete source
        For Each Itm In readItemIDDictionaryFromFile().Keys
            _autoCompleteSource.Add(Itm)
        Next
    End Sub
```

```
    Private Function readItemIDDictionaryFromFile() As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Dim pathtofile As String = IO.Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.Substring(0, My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.Length - 21), "ID Dictionary.txt")
        Dim output As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        If File.Exists(pathtofile) Then
            For Each line In IO.File.ReadAllLines(pathtofile)
                Dim parts() As String = line.Split(",")
                output.Add(parts(1), parts(0))
            Next
            Return output
        End If
    End Function
```

Sorry if some of this code was unnecessary to post, I'm pretty lost as to what's causing the error so I just posted everything that runs before it occurs that I think could be related to it.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you have this: `txtManagerEditItemsSearchName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = _autoCompleteSource` in the `TextChanged` event of another TextBox? Remove that line. Set the auto complete source once, or when you generate a new list of strings. -- You should clarify the relation between `txtManagerEditItemsName` and `txtManagerEditItemsSearchName`. The DataGridView (if that's what it is) appears unrelated. -- It looks like it's a WinForms app. In this case, tag the question accordingly.

Comment: [@Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) Thank you for the advice, I've edited my post and source code accordingly.

Comment: Please, rollback the edit related to the code. Don't change the code you posted here, test what has been suggested in your code base, otherwise nothing make sense anymore.  --  You have (or, you had) events that re-set the same autocomplete custom source more than once, not clear based on what condition. Now, you have a Button that resets the whole thing and it's also not clear what relation there is with everything else you have posted. Then, you have *Then this code runs when you start typing in the AutoCorrect box* a condition that shouldn't exist, which resets the custom source again...

Comment: Try to post a code sample that reproduces the issue, otherwise it's quite complicated to reconstruct what you might possibly be doing there, besides what you have posted already, which appears to be quite wrong in many departments.

Comment: @Jimi I reverted my post. I removed the _Then this code runs when you start typing in the AutoCorrect box_ section and moved the code into `btnManagerEditItem_Click` and it seems to have stopped the crashing but I have no idea why. Not 100% sure if I should mark this question as answered yet but I'm more than happy to. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The AutoComplete feature is only (very) partially handled by the Framework, it's a Shell thing. This is the main function: [SHAutoComplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shautocomplete). You have to treat it with respect, otherwise it may backfire (in your case, going *out of sync*, trying to act on something that is not where it was supposed to be).

Comment: In practice, never change the AutoCompleSource *on the fly*. Or proceed with caution if/when it's actually needed. Never when this may cause cascading events that may trigger the AutoComplete or text changes in the meanwhile. Some code may try to access memory addresses that are not valid anymore.